# Laravel jwtauth

Tags: php, laravel-5, jwt

I'm trying to setup `JWTAuth` in `Laravel 5.2`. I've installed everything and when I try to get a token it succeed.

**Route file:**

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

$api->version('v1',function($api)
{
    $api->group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function($api)
    {
        $api->post('login','App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@authenticate');
    });
});
```

**AuthController@authenticate:**

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        // grab credentials from the request
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        try {
            // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
            if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }

        // all good so return the token
        return response()->json(compact('token'));
    }
```

**Result:**

```
{"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjEsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2xuanN1cHBvcnQuZGV2XC9hcGlcL3YxXC9sb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTQ2MTg0MzM1OCwiZXhwIjoxNDYxODQ2OTU4LCJuYmYiOjE0NjE4NDMzNTgsImp0aSI6IjEyMThiNWUxNTNmNTBhMTA1ZTBhYTE1ZTlhMjRiYjNlIn0.0MpOWMvd2swqI-3r9hNjkjmrpVgNIDds0srlgjXKFVg"}
```

Then when I try to get a user like this:

`Route file` (url: `/users`)(with middleware):

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

$api->version('v1',function($api)
{
    $api->group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'middleware' => 'api.auth'], function($api)
    {
        $api->post('login','App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@authenticate');
        $api->post('users','App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@index');
    });
});
```

**AuthController@index**

```
public function index()
{
    return User::all();
}
```

Header:
Authorization  Bearer {token})

I receive the error:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

What's wrong here?

**--EDIT1--**

When I give a wrong token I receive the error:

```
{"message":"Could not decode token: The token
```

**--EDIT2--**

```
+------+--------+---------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+
| Host | Method | URI           | Name | Action                                                | Protected | Version(s) | Scope(s) | Rate Limit |
+------+--------+---------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+
|      | POST   | /api/v1/login |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@authenticate | No        | v1         |          |            |
|      | POST   | /api/v1/users |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@index        | No        | v1         |          |            |
+------+--------+---------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: Are you visiting `/v1/users` or just `/users`?

Comment: I visit `/api/v1/users` I use the same url for receiving the token so it should be working.(In my `dingo` api file I've set a prefix of `api` )

Comment: could you show what `php artisan route:list` generates ?

Comment: It shows Your application doesn't have any routes. I guess because I use dingo?

Comment: Yes true! its `api:routes` this command

Comment: Please see edit 2 for the result

Comment: You want to get users right? But you have `POST` method or users

Answer (score 0):

Use `GET` method:

`$api->get('users','App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@index');`

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't matter. Still receive the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that I had a middleware activated in my AuthController:

```
public function __construct()
{
   $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
}
```

Comment: I see, that was out of picture then.